# regex for images not returning expected

Tags: javascript, xml, regex, image, titanium

I have used the following regex to search for images in a tag in a feed:

```
var str=items.item(i).getElementsByTagName("content:encoded").item(0).text;
var patt1=/([a-z\-_0-9\/\:\.]*\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif))/i
var urlMatch = str.match(patt1);
```

I am then printing to the console urlMatch[0] , urlMatch[1] and urlMatch[2] for within the following tag:

```
<![CDATA[
<p><a href="http://www.highlandradio.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Emergency.jpg"><img class="alignleft size-thumbnail wp-image-56646" alt="Emergency" src="http://www.highlandradio.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Emergency-150x150.jpg" width="150" height="150" /></a></p> <p><strong>The HSE has confi
]]>
```

This is returning the following 3 results respectively:

```
http://www.highlandradio.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Emergency.jpg,
http://www.highlandradio.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Emergency.jpg, 
jpg.
```

Can someone explain to me what is going on? Why I am not getting the one with the 150x150 in the name? This is the one I need. Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting multiple groups for the first match, instead of multiple matches. That means, `urlMatch[0]` is the match, `urlMatch[1]` is the first capturing group (the first set of parentheses, incidentally identical with the entire match), and `urlMatch[2]` is the second set of parentheses in your pattern (which you have wrapped around the file extension).

You need to use global `g` flag:

```
var patt1=/([a-z\-_0-9\/\:\.]*\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif))/ig;
var urlMatch = str.match(patt1);
```

Resulting in:

```
[
  "http://www.highlandradio.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Emergency.jpg",
  "http://www.highlandradio.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Emergency-150x150.jpg"
]
```

If you *do* need the capturing groups (in addition to all matches), you'll have to use [`RegExp.exec()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec).

If not, you can use non-capturing groups, to improve performance. Note that you won't need the outer parentheses in any case, so you can leave out anyway. Using non-capturing groups, this would look like:

```
var patt1 = /[a-z\-_0-9´\/:.]*\.(?:jpg|jpeg|png|gif)/ig;
```